# Align label in Stetic GUI designer

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I currently have the problem that my labels are centered in the parent VBox, which lies in a Fixed Container.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Change the Xalign for the label to be 0. By default it is 0.5 which will center the text. Setting this to 0 will tell Gtk to align the text to the left.

You can find this in the Miscellanous Alignment Properties in the Properties window.

[image: Misc alignment properties in Properties window]

Answer (score 0):

The "Miscellaneous Alignment Properties" list in the designer properties control is where you specify vertical and horizontal justification.

Horizontal (`XAlign`):

- 0 is left-aligned
- 0.5 is centered
- 1 is right-aligned

Vertical (`YAlign`):

- 0 is aligned to the TOP
- 0.5 is centered
- 1 is aligned to the BOTTOM

On controls (such as the label) that provide a Justification property in the Stetic designer (which is used by Visual Studio for the Mac) the Justification property is ignored.